# ExpressJs req.body showing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, post

I am new to ExpressJs, i want to perform a POST request, but i can't get the Body Parser to work

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const config = require("./config");
// const logger = require("./middleware/logger")

// init express
const app = express();

// set 'public' as STATIC directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// init middleware
// app.use(logger);

// setup parent router for api/people
app.use('/api/people', require("./routes/api/members"));

// adding body parser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


// set PORT listen
app.listen(config.PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `damiisdandy's server running on port ${config.PORT}... at ${config.time}`
  )
);
```

here is the routing file

```js
const express = require('express')
const uuid = require('uuid')
const config = require('../../config')
const router = express.Router();


router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
    // const newMember = {
    //     id: uuid.v4(),
    //     name: req.body.name,
    //     email: req.body.email,
    //     active: true,
    // }
    // if(!newMember.name || !newMember.email) {
    //     return res.status(400).json({
    //         msg: "Please Fill in the Name or Email"}
    //     );
    // }
    // config.PEOPLE.push(newMember);
    // res.json(config.PEOPLE);
})

module.exports = router
```

please i would love a quick response, i have even tried "body-parser" module, but that doesnt seem to work either.. i am stuck .. please what can i do?

Comment: what does `console.log(req.body)` shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not applying to your routes because your `.use` statements are after your parent router.

You need to move these above your parent router like this:

```
// adding body parser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// setup parent router for api/people
app.use('/api/people', require("./routes/api/members"));
```

I believe you don't need to install or apply bodyParser explicitly because express comes with it built in now. Try this and tell if it works and we can explore further if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have there 3 lines in your index.js file?

```
// import body parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: You don't need to use `body-parser` anymore because `express` have these functions inbuilt from version 4.x and above